# Functional: Term does not evaluate error on functional 1149

Tags: c++, std-function, stdbind

I don't understand the error in this. I'm trying to use `std::function`s to pass a member function as an argument. It works fine except for in the 4th and final case.

```
void window::newGame() {

}
//show options
void window::showOptions() {

}
 void window::showHelp() {

}
//Quits program
void window::quitWindow() {
    close();
}
void window::createMenu() {

    std::function<void()> newGameFunction = std::bind(&window::newGame);

    std::function<void()> showOptionsFunction = std::bind(&window::showOptions);


    std::function<void()> showHelpFunction = std::bind(&window::showHelp);


    std::function<void()> quitWindowFunction = std::bind(&window::quitWindow);
}
```

No errors in the first 3 usages of `std::function`, however in the final usage I get the follow:

`Error  1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 0 arguments` on line 1149 of `functional`.

I only know that the error occurs on the line because I took out all the other ones and that was the only one that caused any issue with a variety of combinations.

Comment: Unless the first 3 functions are static, none of them should work. Member functions require pointer to an object of the class. Not knowing what your code does, I'd say try this: `... = std::bind(&window::quitWindow, this)`

Comment: Hmm...I guess it just wasn't showing the errors then. Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those should compile. Member functions are special: they need an object. So you have two choices: you can bind them with an object, or you can have them take an object.

```
// 1) bind with object
std::function<void()> newGameFunction = std::bind(&window::newGame, this);
                                                             //   ^^^^^^
std::function<void()> showOptionsFunction = std::bind(&window::showOptions, this);

// 2) have the function *take* an object
std::function<void(window&)> showHelpFunction = &window::showHelp;
std::function<void(window*)> quitWindowFunction = &window::quitWindow;
```

The latter two can be called like:

```
showHelpFunction(*this); // equivalent to this->showHelp();
quitWindowFunction(this); // equivalent to this->quitWindow();
```

It ultimately depends on your use-case for the `function`s which way you want to do it - but either way you definitely need a `window` in there somewhere!